# How to align Text- left, right and center into Flutter?

Tags: flutter

I have three text- named as News-Title, News-date, and News-description. I want News title alignment as left, below to news-title want news-date right aligned and below to news-date wants news-description with center alignment.

please suggest proper solution.....

Comment: can you please share code what you had tried so far

Comment: Please share code than will able to reply

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below code hope its help to you. just set Alignment in your column refer [**`layout`**](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/ui/layout) and [**`Align-class`**](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Align-class.html)

```
Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,//add this line if you used column widget in your code
        children: [
          Text('News-Title'),
          Text('News-date'),
          Text('News-description'),
        ],
      ),
```

Result-> [image]

Answer (score 1):

Use `Align`. You can choose [alignment](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Align-class.html) property value based on requirements.

```
Align(
   alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
   child: Text(
          "News Title",
          style: TextStyle(
          color: Colors.black),
   )
),
```

Answer (score 1):

Either -

```
Align(
   alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
   child: Text(
          "News Title",
          style: TextStyle(
          color: Colors.black),
   )
),
```

Or that -

```
Text(
              "News Title",
              textAlign: TextAlign.center //example
              style: TextStyle(
              color: Colors.black),)
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you try to use `TextAlignment.center` / left/ right? or you could wrap it in the Align class from here https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Align-class.html